# Selenium Run multiple browser instances parallely

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
       if (platform != null) {
                        for (final String p : platform) {
                            log.info("Platform " + p);
                            executorService.submit(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    try {
                                        runService(p, config, url, title, report);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }

                        executorService.shutdown();
                        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE,
                                TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

                        // for(final String p: platform){
                        // runUIService(p, config, url, title, report);
                        // }
                    }

    public void runService(){
              WebDriver driver = getDriver();
//some selenium operations performed
    }
```

I am trying to execute runService() in multiple threads parallelly. getDriver() method returns a new instance of selenium WebDriver. If I execute for a single platform all the selenium operations run successfully, but if the same code is fired for multiple platforms although a new browser instance is opened for each platform, I am getting a lot of errors on selenium elements not found. I am not able to figure what can be the reason for this ? Is there a problem associated with running multiple browser instances through selenium at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a concurrency issue.
Have you tried using synchronized keyword for your method?
i.e
public synchronized void runService()

or in your getDriver() method.

Hope this can help.